# friendly way to echo slow loading data

Tags: php

I have the following web php code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM))
{
printf("<p>ID: %s</p>", $row[0]);
echo exec ("php analysis.php " .escapeshellcmd($row[0]));
}
```

For a set of 4k users, the following code takes 15 minutes to execute with the results being displayed in increments of of ~1k users.

I want the results displayed at around the speed that the code is going so that anybody using the page is confused as to weather or not the code works. Is there some way to force the browser to display the data it was sent?

edit:
`Flush` is not producing noticeably different output.
edit:
My problem remains unresolved? Is there some client server model that can be implemented in JavaScript to facilitate this? Can Javascript open a socket and interrupt on socket data? Maybe using flash(which I know can use sockets...)

Comment: Why don't you put everything in `analysis.php` into a function, `include()` the file once and then call the function from within your loop? Using `exec` for that seems like overkill (and you should use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) for escaping arguments, not `escapeshellcmd`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo exec(...)` waits before the command is finished. If you do not mind showing partial info, use `passthru(...)`.

Depending on your webserver, [flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) may work or not. If output buffering is enabled (implicitly using `ob_start()` or explicitly in php.ini), [ob_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) needs to be called as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set it up as a stream and `fread` from it? Combined with `flush`.

I'm always running into solid walls when trying to read output from `exec` or `system` or one of the many ways to call command-line programs from PHP ~_~

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the output buffer using [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM))
{
  printf("<p>ID: %s</p>", $row[0]);
  echo exec ("php analysis.php " .escapeshellcmd($row[0]));
  flush();
}
```

If your server uses output buffering, use `ob_flush` after calling `ob_start` at the start of the script.